# jslint warning "Don't make functions within a loop" only for functions referencing outside variables?

Tags: javascript, jshint

I have two anonymous functions created inside a loop, but `jshint` only gives a warning when the anon function references a variable not passed to it.

Why is this?

```
(function(){
  for(var i=0; i<5; ++i){
    var age = 9001;
    //This has a jshint warning, as it uses age
    var cutoffs = [1800,12000].map(function(cutoff){
      return cutoff < age;
    });
    //but this doesn't cause a warning, despite creating a function inside a loop
    var cutoffs2 = [1800,12000].map(function(cutoff){
      return cutoff < 42;
    });
  }
})();
```

Comment: Just ignore this, the linting is bad and think you have declaring a function inside a loop.

Comment: @Eric But I am declaring a function inside the loop, I'm just curious as to why it doesn't give a warning for both functions declared inside the loop.

Comment: I wonder if it's because the reduce function does not refer to anything from the closure - so can it be optimized by runtime? nothing to base this on, but that is one difference between the two.

Comment: I think it might be the fact that the one is multi-line and the other isn't. the linter is seeing the single line function as inline while the multi-line would appear to be a full function call.

Comment: @JustinMacArthur It's not that, just tested.

Comment: @mtfurlan ah, good experimental evidence.

Comment: @DougMoscrop That seems to be it. `jshint` only gives a warning if outside variables are referenced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just a bad warning that should have been changed.

From the [jshint issue](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/3056#issuecomment-257111696) I opened:

> This warning was initially reported for all functions
>   within a loop. It wasn't until gh-1887 (released in version 2.5.7) that the
>   warning was limited to specific cases according to the bindings around which it
>   closed. The text probably should have been updated at that time, as well.

It will be fixed by [jshint pull request 3058](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/pull/3058), whenever that gets dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

Add long as the function executes synchronousy within the loop (before the next irritation) or doesn't reference the counter (i) there won't be any unexpected results.

See http://linterrors.com/js/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop for a full explanation of the issue and a workaround

https://github.com/jshint/jshint/pull/1887#issuecomment-57963322

> Just a fleeting thought... why stop here? In fact, the only dangerous loop function is one that uses the loop variables itself inside the function without closing it over.
>
> I get that this is a step in the right direction, but use of outer scope variables isn't what's dangerous here, it's loop variables themselves. We should make this check even MORE lenient.