# Can't reference variable in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I have the following code below however ESlint doesn't like it giving

> Function declared in loop contains unsafe references to variable 'result'

How can I rewrite this to remove that problem? I'm trying to use "result" to return result of function.

```
  const checkEventOverlap1 = (sectionsToUpdate) => {
    var i;
    let result = false;

    for(i = 0; i < sectionsToUpdate.length; i++){
      const firstSelectedEventStartTime = new Date(sectionsToUpdate[i].recurrence.timePeriod.startOn);
      const firstSelectedEventRelatedCourse = sectionsToUpdate[i].section16.course16.id;
      const selectedEventDays = sectionsToUpdate[i].recurrence.repeatRule.daysOfWeek;

      const removedSection = sectionsToUpdate.splice(i, 1);

      sectionsToUpdate.forEach(sectionToUpdate => {
        const previousEventDays = sectionToUpdate.recurrence.repeatRule.daysOfWeek;
        const previousEventRelatedCourse = sectionToUpdate.section16.course16.id;
        const eventStartTime = new Date(sectionToUpdate.recurrence.timePeriod.startOn);
        const eventEndTime = new Date(sectionToUpdate.recurrence.timePeriod.endOn);

        // Ensure days dont clash (eg Monday = Monday), if they do then there is a clash possibilty
        if(previousEventDays.some(day => selectedEventDays.includes(day)) && previousEventRelatedCourse !== firstSelectedEventRelatedCourse){
          // We have a day match now check if there is a time clash, if so we have an overlap so set result to true
          if((eventStartTime <= firstSelectedEventStartTime || eventStartTime >= firstSelectedEventStartTime) && firstSelectedEventStartTime <= eventEndTime){
            console.log("yup");
            result = true;
          }
        }
      });
      sectionsToUpdate.splice(i, 0, removedSection[0]);
      console.log(sectionsToUpdate);
    }
    return result;
  };
```

Comment: What exactly is the error message you're getting?

Comment: Function declared in loop contains unsafe references to variable 'result'

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Comment: That is not JavaScript that is ESLint that gives that message

Comment: Have a look at other [answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=function+declared+in+a+loop+unsafe+references+to+variable+site:stackoverflow.com) to the same question

Comment: The question that supposedly already answers this doesn't have an accepted answer or link to the relevant docs.

Comment: It should instead be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40224036/jslint-warning-dont-make-functions-within-a-loop-only-for-functions-referenci/40662761

Comment: Unlike the linked duplicate question this should be valid safe code, as the function declared in the loop runs synchronously immediately.